# Difference in the output when a value is given in the program and when user input is given

Tags: java, inputstream

```
public class ForComma {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("enter j");
        int j = (int) System.in.read();
        for(int i=0; i<j ; j--, i++){
            System.out.println("i is " + i + "\tj is " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `for-loop`, when `j` is defined as **j=10**, the result is different with the result when **10** is entered as an user input. Why?

Comment: could you include a sample input, the actuall output and your expected output inside the question please.

Comment: `System.in.read()` does not do what you think it does - it reads the next `byte` from the input stream (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)

Comment: When you write `10` into your console, then it is equal to `j=49` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using `System.in.read()` to get value from console.

It will actually read next byte of data, which in your case is 1 as ascii code i.e. 49

Just replace your code with this:

```
for(i=0,j=Integer.parseInt(System.in.readLine());i<j;j--,i++){
```

Comment: What does Integer.parseInt() exactly do?

Comment: `System.in.readLine()` gives you a String, `Integer.parseInt` parses this string into an Integer

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`System.in.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) to read user input and it is wrong.

When input is given to the console, it will be given to our software as a `Stream`. Streams are special. They don't give everything once. They give the values you entered in the console, character by character.

If you enter **10** in the console and when you press enter key the characters will be given to the Stream. Once you call `read()`, `49` will be given as the output(As 49 is the `ASCII` value of 1). The next time you call `read()`, `48` will be given as the output(As 48 is the `ASCII` value of 0). The next time you call `read()`, `13` will be given as the output(As 13 is the `ASCII` value of enter key).

So, you will have to read all those 3 bytes in order to determine the value the user enter. But you don't need to worry. `Java` has classes where this task is done and we just have to call the needed method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ForComma {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.print("Enter j: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < j; j--, i++) {
            System.out.println("i is " + i + "\tj is " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.in.read` doku:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown. 
>   A subclass must provide an implementation of this method.

So what happens? System.in.read actually reads the input, but just the next chunk of byte. In fact for the input `10` this is just the one. 
This results in an `int` value of `49`.

If you parse this value to a `char` then you will notice that you got the ascii representation of the `char` `1` and not the `int` value for the number `10`.